# JQuery FadeIn/Out & Delay rendering problem in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

my browser (Firefox v3.6.13) is having problems rendering the text making the color greenish and crispy (please see the image below). Is there a solution to this problem?

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script language="javascript">
function showProjects(){  
            var index = 0; 
            $(".parent_div").children().each(function(i) { 
                $(this).delay(250*index++).fadeIn(3500);
            });

        };
</script>
<body>
<div class="parent_div">
      <a  id="test1" href="#" style="display:none">Something 1</a>
      <a  id="test2" href="#" style="display:none">Something 2</a>
      <a  id="test3" href="#" style="display:none">Something 3</a>                   
</div>
</body>
```

Also, I tried changing my jquery script to:

```
     $(this).delay(250*index++).fadeIn(3500, function(){
       this.style.removeAttribute("filter"); // Suggested on other websites, but still doesn't work :(
     });
```

Thanks,
partizan

Comment: Hi Partizan, i tried to generate you problem here (http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/k38rZ/). Are you able to set up an example of this error or give me the link to it. With the code you have given i cannot reproduce the problem. By the way the "filter" style only applies to IE so removing it won't affect Firefox. The Firefox equivilent is opacity so you could try removing that.

Comment: Timothy, your example demonstrates the issue I'm having since it's not smooth on my browser Firefox v3.6. I get the impression that you see it nice and smooth on your machine. Which browser are you running the example here jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/k38rZ?

Comment: I tried running FF3.6.16 on XP and your problem doesn't occur. I have changed the example for you to look at. I have moved away from fade in and fade out. Take a look at it and try it again.

Comment: Thats ok. A tick on my answer would be fantastic :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3421

Seems that "The definitive fix for ClearType opacity problem is: Set a background color to parent object"

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but that didn't fix the problem. I ensured that the background color of the parent object DIV and even its parent are set explicitly to WHITE (#fff). I'm still seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/k38rZ). The fade in doesn't quite work for me but it seems like a work around for your problem. IE doesn't use opacity by the way as well. I think it uses filter.